# Add button flip animation - Android

Tags: android, android-animation, imagebutton

I have an app which uses a camera,

There is an option there which allows to switch camera ,
**When that button is clicked I would like to flip the button and for it to return to the original state**, I cant seem to find a solution to it or a way of doing so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show some code and be more specific. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the scale attributes in `ImageView`

When that button is clicked if you want to flip the button and for it to return to the original state

```
android:scaleX="-1" //To flip horizontally 
android:scaleY="-1" //To flip vertically
```

And vice-versa

Example :

```
float scalingFactor = 0.5f; // scale down to half the size
view.setScaleX(scalingFactor);
view.setScaleY(scalingFactor);
```

Comment: isnt this answer helped you? @2D3D

Answer (score 0):

Example exist at Android Developer Guides:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_card_flip.mp4

For use Animation to single view (not all screen) use View.setAnimation()

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.card_flip_left_in); 
myView.setAnimation(a);
a.startNow();
```

create animation xmls:

**card_flip_left_in.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

**card_flip_left_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

**card_flip_right_in.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

**card_flip_right_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

Comment: You did not understand what I am trying to achieve , Only the button will flip not the entire screen

Comment: It's not necessary. Use this animations for single view
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.card_flip_left_in); 
myView.setAnimation(a);
a.startNow();

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectAnimator like this:

```
    cameraSwitchButton.setImageResource(icon1ResourceId);

    cameraSwitchButton.setOnClickListener({                          
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cameraSwitchButton, "scaleX", 0.0f).setDuration(100);
            animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    cameraSwitchButton.setImageResource(icon2ResourceId);
                    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(cameraSwitchButton, "scaleX", 1.0f).setDuration(100).start();
                }
            });
            animator.start(); 

            // Camera switch logic here...
    });
```

If you want to flip it back, decide which icon you need at these lines:

```
cameraSwitchButton.setImageResource(icon(1 or 2)ResourceId);
```